# FileNotFound error in Sqoop Merge command

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to execute a sqoop merge command and for that, I have executed a Sqoop codegen to get the class and the jar of the table into the HDFS

Sqoop CodeGen Command:

```
sqoop codegen --connect jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mydb --table mergetab --username root --password cloudera --outdir /user/cloudera/codegenclasses --fields-terminated-by '\t'
```

I have the following files in the outdir: /user/cloudera/codegenclasses

```
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera       9572 2017-04-20 16:26 codegenclasses/mergetab.class
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera       3902 2017-04-20 16:26 codegenclasses/mergetab.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera      12330 2017-04-20 16:26 codegenclasses/mergetab.java
```

I am running the below sqoop merge command to update the rows in my hive table:

```
sqoop merge --merge-key id --new-data /user/cloudera/incrdata/incrementaldata --onto /user/cloudera/hivetables/fulltabledata --target-dir /user/cloudera/updateddatam --class-name /user/cloudera/codegenclasses/mergetab.class --jar-file /user/cloudera/codegenclasses/mergetab.jar
```

But Im getting the error:

```
Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /user/cloudera/codegenclasses/44059c9b2bd47b95f03866d8d93eff7f/mergetab.jar does not exist
```

I have all the files in the folder and I gave the proper directories. But Im unable to identify the mistake Im doing here.
Could anyone help me fixing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the argument `--outdir <dir>`, the `<dir>` path specified belongs to the local filesystem. And using `--outdir` will only store the generated code i.e., `tablename.java`. Use `--bindir <dir>` instead.

```
sqoop codegen --connect jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mydb --table mergetab --username root --password cloudera --bindir /path/to/store/jarfile --fields-terminated-by '\t'
```

Then `merge`. By default, the table name is the `--class-name`.

```
sqoop merge --merge-key id --new-data /user/cloudera/incrdata/incrementaldata --onto /user/cloudera/hivetables/fulltabledata --target-dir /user/cloudera/updateddatam --class-name mergetab --jar-file /path/to/store/jarfile/mergetab.jar
```